# Delphi 6: How can I change created filedate (= file creation date)

Tags: file, delphi, date, delphi-6

I've been searching now for HOURS on Google (and here).

And I cannot find a solution.

I want to **CHANGE** the "**Created** Filetime" (= creation filetime) in **DELPHI 6**.

Not the "Modified file time" (for which a simple call to "FileSetDate()" is needed)
and not the "Last accessed file time".

How do I do this?

[image: Picture of what I mean...]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function. Pass `nil` for `lpLastAccessTime` and `lpLastWriteTime` if you only want to modify the creation time.

You will need to obtain a file handle by calling [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or one of the Delphi wrappers, so this is not the most convenient API to use.

Make life easier for yourself by wrapping the API call up in a helper function that receives the file name and a `TDateTime`. This function should manage the low-level details of obtaining and closing a file handle, and converting the `TDateTime` to a `FILETIME`.

I would do it like this:

```
const
  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = $0100;

procedure SetFileCreationTime(const FileName: string; const DateTime: TDateTime);
var
  Handle: THandle;
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
  FileTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Handle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName), FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
    FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if Handle=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    DateTimeToSystemTime(DateTime, SystemTime);
    if not SystemTimeToFileTime(SystemTime, FileTime) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    if not SetFileTime(Handle, @FileTime, nil, nil) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Handle);
  end;
end;
```

I had to add the declaration of `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` because it is not present in the Delphi 6 Windows unit.

Comment: Problem time CET and UTC +1

Comment: I can confirm that. (German time) You need to change `DateTimeToSystemTime(DateTime, SystemTime)` to `DateTimeToSystemTime(DateTimeToUTC(DateTime), SystemTime)` . A possible implementation for `DateTimeToUTC` can be found here: https://www.delphipraxis.net/207745-utc-local-time.html

Answer (score 7):

Based on [`FileSetDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FileSetDate), you can write a similar routine:

```
function FileSetCreatedDate(Handle: Integer; Age: Integer): Integer;
var
  LocalFileTime, FileTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if DosDateTimeToFileTime(LongRec(Age).Hi, LongRec(Age).Lo, LocalFileTime) and
    LocalFileTimeToFileTime(LocalFileTime, FileTime) and
    SetFileTime(Handle, @FileTime, nil, nil) then Exit;
  Result := GetLastError;
end;
```